# Installing tcl/tk R package on windows

Tags: r, installation, tcl

It appears that the cran version has been removed, and I cannot seem to find any info on how to install it with a quick google search. I installed tcltk following the steps here:https://www.tcl.tk/doc/howto/compile.html . Is there a way to get the tcltk package on R after it has been removed from cran? Running `install.packages("tcltk")` just returns

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tcltk’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘tcltk’ is a base package, and should not be updated
```

which I presume this is due to tcltk no longer being on cran.

Comment: I have `R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)` on Windows and I was able to run `library(tcltk);  tcl("info", "tclversion")`  Did you build R yourself rather than download the version from CRAN?  Do you have the 2019-12-12 version of R 3.6.2 or some other version?

Comment: I believe I built it myself. I also do have the 2019-12-12 version

Comment: If you built it yourself then you need to be sure to build it with tcltk at the time you build it.  You can't add it later if you did not build it with tcltk in the first place.  If you download R from CRAN then it should already have tcltk.